# How to separate array list value with comma and put in hashmap

Tags: android, json, post, arraylist, hashmap

I have this kind of data in sessionList

[image]

Now I want to run a loop and put this data inside hashmap i.e. key and value pair because I then want to post hashmap data to URL so I need all the values from session list to be mapped in a hashmap

**I tried with something like this** but it doesn't work.

```
 Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int count = 0; count < sessionList.size(); count++) {

 stringMap.put("booking_session[sessions]["+date+"][game_session]
 [" + count+"]", sessionList.get(count).split(",")[0]
        }
```

As you can see I am putting some string values in string map with 'date' and count values as variables so that the retrieved value can be filled in it. This '**date**' value should be filled by the sessionList data that is before the comma and this line **'sessionList.get(count).split(",")[0]'** should be filled with sessionList data after comma i.e. the **time session** value.

**So basically the conclusion is:**

1- SessionList data before comma at all indexes should be filled in 'date' variable and data after comma at all indexes should be filled in 'value' field of the hashmap. How can I achieve that? Please Help

Comment: What you want for `[" + count+"]"` ?

Comment: HashMap is <Key, Value> pair. do you want DATE (Before comma result) as key and TIME(After comma result) as Value?

Comment: @jettimadhuChowdary yes exactly that is what i want

Comment: for (int count = 0; count < sessionList.size(); count++) {
                            String[] splitResult = sessionList.get(count).split(",");
                            stringMap.put(splitResult[0], splitResult[1]);
                        }

Comment: @jettimadhuChowdary thankyou so much, i have got the answer from Prithvi and you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your code is working for most of the case, please check the below solution.

```
Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int count = 0; count < sessionList.size(); count++) {
    stringMap.put("booking_session[sessions][" + sessionList.get(count).split(",")[0] + "][game_session] [" + count + "]", sessionList.get(count).split(",")[1]);
}
```

***OR***

```
Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int count = 0; count < sessionList.size(); count++) {
    String[] result = sessionList.get(count).split(",");
    stringMap.put(result[0], result[1]);
}
```

Comment: Good to know. :)